# Pet Door For Multiple Animals

Tags: dogs, cats, outdoor

We live in western Washington in the US (winter low temperatures are usually above freezing, rarely in the teens). I'm thinking about putting in a pet door for three animals: a largish cat (about 12 pounds and quite agile), a middle aged toy poodle, and a young standard poodle.

I'd been leaning towards the through wall model of the [Patio Pacific Endure Pet Door](http://www.endurapetdoor.com/Wall_Mount_Dog_Door.html) in a size 10 (10" x 18" flap) until I read some reviews which said that cats and small dogs have problems with these doors. It sounds like the closure that seals the door well also makes it difficult for small animals to open.

Am I likely to be able to find a door that will accommodate all three animals? Even though we don't have severe winter weather, previous doors have gotten unpleasantly drafty over time.

Comment: There is the solution of using two doors...

Comment: Thank you. That is an option, but space is tight, and decent door seem expensive, so I was hoping for some wisdom before plunging in…

Comment: I've seen cat doors installed in basement windows, if that helps at all... There are multiple reasons I've only used pet doors internally, and weather seal is certainly one of them; balancing that against force needed to open might be tough.